# jQuery.ajax is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call the following function in some javascript code. The JS code that's calling it is actually an example from the Javascript InfoVis tutorial. I try to call a server so that I can use the return value to draw a custom graph. The error I get in FireBug is "jQuery.ajax is not a function".

I have an HTML page that loads both the jQuery script and InfoVis tutorial. Is something wrong with the example below?

mj

```
jQuery.Ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/applications/nvn",
    data: "GetNVN",
    success: function(msg){
    var fdsa;
    fdsa++;
    init(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: try $.ajax? i don't know if that would make a difference but that is what i use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is lowercase. JavaScript is case sensitive, so `Ajax` and `ajax` are two different things.

If the tutorial was using `Ajax()`, it would be worth contacting them and letting them know the error.